# How to Monitor Neo4j metrics with Graphite?

Tags: neo4j, graphite

I'm trying to monitor Neo4j with Graphite, as mentioned in document: [Chapter 6. Monitoring](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/).

I pulled the Graphite docker image from [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/sitespeedio/graphite/), and started by:

`sudo docker run -d \
  --name graphite \
  -p 8080:80 \
  -p 2003:2003 \
  sitespeedio/graphite`

Then I restarted Neo4j, and opened `localhost:8080` in browser. **But how do I add Neo4j metrics to monitor?** And, **does Neo4j push metrics to graphite via the default port 2003?**

Comment: Juste paste the configuration from the doc line mentioned by cmur2, make sure to adapt the host to your docker host (192.168.99.100 on os x for eg), it just work out of the box

Answer (score 2):

If you already configured Neo4j as described in the document you mentioned [Chapter 6. Monitoring](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/) with the provided example configuration snippet it should be sending metrics automatically to graphite (as long as your network setup permits it).

You can check that using the graphite web frontend running on `localhost:8080` by browsing the tree view on the right for the `metrics prefix` configured in Neo4j.